# Check if any Existing workflows are in progress in SharePoint 2013 Visual studio WF development

Tags: 2013, visual-studio-2013, workflow-manager

I am using visual studio 2013 to create SharePoint workflows in SP2013. We have already have workflows associated with a document library and now while creating a new one, I want to check if the existing workflows are progress or not. How to proceed with this condition?

Answer (score 1):

You may check the `SPListItem.Workflows` property on a given list item (e.g. the current list item) (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.workflows.aspx). That would give you the list of WF instances running in the scope of that item.